# Finding a left- and right-multiplied matrix A given the product

Tags: matrices

I am working my way through [this book](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=Franz%20E.%20Hohn&tn=Elementary%20Matrix%20Algebra&cm_sp=mbc-_-ats-_-all), in an attempt to teach myself matrix algebra. In the first chapter, the author asks the student to find a matrix $A$ such that:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}\times A\times \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 4 \\ 3 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

I don't think the book went over the process for finding this solution, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be the left matrix of the left hand side. Also, let $C$ be the right matrix of the left hand side.

Then, multiply $B^{-1}$ from the left side, and multiply $C^{-1}$ from the right side.

Edit : Since we have
$$BAC=D$$
where $D$ is a matrix in the right hand side, we have
$$B^{-1}BACC^{-1}=B^{-1}DC^{-1}.$$
Since each of $B^{-1}B$ and $CC^{-1}$ is an identity matrix, we have
$$A=B^{-1}DC^{-1}.$$
I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by "from the right side" or "from the left side". Can you just take a bit of time to write it out?

Comment: @ixtmixilix: I added some explanation.